# How to add clickable image on button?

Tags: extjs

I have a panel I want to completely fill that panel with button and button  has two clickable image and text. clicking on both the image will trigger the different action. How should I do it. Code snippet will be helpful? (should I use segmented button)

Comment: You should do it by trying something based on research and experimentation, then focusing your question on the specific issue where you are stuck.

Comment: I have treid using sigmented button but it is not covering the panel container

Comment: can you not simply use 2 buttons? why must they be the same?